# Ceedling command always outputs a weird string. Why does this happen?

Tags: ruby, ceedling

I just installed Ceedling for the first time. I did it by installing ruby via Msys2 using `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-ruby` which installed ruby version 3.1.3-2 and then ran `gem install ceedling` in cmd.

Now, whenever I run any command from ceedling I get this output

```
Welcome to Ceedling!
Calling `DidYouMean::SPELL_CHECKERS.merge!(error_name => spell_checker)' has been deprecated. Please call `DidYouMean.correct_error(error_name, spell_checker)' instead.
```

Followed by the correct output.

For example, I can write `ceedling version` and I get the output:

```
Welcome to Ceedling!
Calling `DidYouMean::SPELL_CHECKERS.merge!(error_name => spell_checker)' has been deprecated. Please call `DidYouMean.correct_error(error_name, spell_checker)' instead.
    Ceedling:: 0.31.1
       CMock:: 2.5.4
       Unity:: 2.5.4
  CException:: 1.3.3
```

Why is this happening? Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue in Ceedling.

https://github.com/ThrowTheSwitch/Ceedling/issues/659

Is fixed in the upcoming 0.32 release.

Your options:

1. Ignore the warning, it's just a warning and does not break anything.
2. Downgrade ruby to 3.0 or lower.
3. Upgrade Ceedling to the currently unreleased 0.32 version.